# Only first parameter accepted in camel cxf

Tags: apache-camel, cxf, apache-servicemix

I have a cxf server defined in camel.xml as:

```
<cxf:rsServer id="rsServer" address="http://0.0.0.0:9090/orderservice"
    serviceClass="my.pakcage.myClass" />
```

I have a REST service defined as:

```
@POST
@Path("/orders/{id}/something")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response changeOrderSomething(@PathParam("id") String orderId, @Body String somethingPayload) {
    return null;
}
```

In Java DSL I have camel route as:

```
from("rsServer?bindingStyle=Default").log("rsServerlogging: ${body}")
            .recipientList(simple("direct-vm:${header.operationName}"));
```

I am calling POST on `/orders/1/something` and in the body I am passing a json: `{"somethingId":"3"}`
Later I have a route which accepts `direct-vm:changeOrderSomething` and passes it to a processor:

```
@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    String body = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
    LOG.info("exchange.getIn body is: {}", body);
}
```

The problem I am facing is that here in the log, body is only "1" which is the path param, which means I am not getting what I am passing as body in the POST request. If I change the order of parameters in REST service as `@Body String somethingPayload, @PathParam("id") String orderId`, I am getting the json that I passed but not the path param. 
What do I do to get everything that I pass as parameters in REST?

**UPDATE**

I made a mistake calling an Object[] somewhere so it threw exception:

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Failed to invoke method: [0] on null due to: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Key: 0 not found in bean: 1 of type: java.lang.String using OGNL path [[0]] while invoking public javax.ws.rs.core.Response my.package.myClass.changeOrderSomething(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) with params [1, {
"somethingId":"3"}]
```

I think this means that the REST webservice is picking up the parameters, but only the first one is passed on to `direct-vm:${header.operationName}` somehow. Maybe I am missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out. The input POST body can be put as the first argument. This makes the Exchange object's body as the passed body. The `@PathParam` or any other parameters can be placed later and accessed through `exchange.getIn().getHeader("id")` since all such parameters are accessed from headers.